# Legit or wrong member usage of class member value?

Tags: c++, oop, arguments, member

****EDIT***
after few comments approving my own opinion based on an hunch
 (pass as an argument)

what i am really after are guidelines for what should or should not be used as class members
****EDIT***

Say that Class Example has 
few public functions

```
   class Example
   {
   public:
      A(int x);
      G();
      H();
      Z();
   private:
      B();
      C();
      D();
      E()
   }
```

A is being called and make calls to A->B->C->D->E.
in E function we need to use the X parameter we got in A , but B,C,D has nothing with it.

one option is to store  int x as class member and then to get it in E.
the other way is to pass it through B->C-D->E as argument.

in my opinion storing it as a member is a bad practice  because it has nothing with the class state or data, but in most of the code i see that is what been done.

tried to google for what is legit usage of class member but didn't found anything.

it feels to me like  member in oop is an altrenative bad practice for  using
globals.

where can i find opinions or data on it ?

i am using c++

Comment: If E depends on x and B depends on the result of E that B has a dependence on x. Therefore, it should be passed to that function.

Comment: It may also make sense to break up the class further. There seems to be a lot going on, which may indicate that the class is ripe for refactoring. But not necessarily.

Comment: would be nice if you could turn the example into real code, it is only little missing to make it valid c++, but it is more than a `;`...(however if you do, consider that one of the answers already quotes the code as is)

Comment: what i am really asking if usage of class member as a way to communicate between two functions is legit . isnt it just like using globals?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818  , i understand your wish , but my question is not on a specific code , more about how to use class members, they  feels to me just like magic globals

Comment: there are no rules to decide between one of your two options, they are both legal and not against any rules of the language. Whether it is good style is a different quesiton which is quite close to being purely opinion-based, though I dont see how one could be in favour of the first solution you describe so maybe not sooo opinion based

Comment: even if it is not about specific code it would be nice if your example would be valid code, you are basically just missing the return types to make it a correct declaration

Comment: ... and a `;` ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 - thanks , i will try:

say that  "bool m_useTcp" is a member i will show you the alternative :

void A(int x)
{
   if (x == 42)
  {
      m_useTcp = true;
  }

 ...
void  B();
}

void B()
{
    C()
}

void C()
{
    if (m_useTcp)
    {
       D();
    }
     else
   {
      E();
   }
}


all voids..

is it makes more sense now to use this bool?

Answer (score 2):

> the other way is to pass it through B->C-D->E as argument.

This option makes a lot of sense.

If E needs an argument, then it should take an argument. If D calls E, then D should provide that argument. If D cannot provide one otherwise, then it also needs that to take that argument, and so on. I recommend this approach.

> in my opinion storing it as a member is a bad practice because it has nothing with the class state or data

This is sound reasoning.

Also consider whether all of those functions refer to the object itself. If not, they should probably be static members, or even free functions.

Comment: @JesperJuhl To somehow produce a value that could be passed to E.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm not native speaker either, so that might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the interface of `A`, `x` does not seem to be intrinsic to the class. Hence, it does not make sense to hold it as a member variable of the class.

If `E` needs it, it has to get it as an argument to the function.
If `D` needs to call `E` with it, it needs to get it as an argument to the function.
So on...

I think your best option is to pass `x` along from `A()` to `E()`.

```
class Example
{
  public:
    A(int x);
    G();
    H();
    Z();
  private:
    B(int x);
    C(int x);
    D(int x);
    E(int x);
};
```

Comment: well , i offered it , but i am trying to understand more about why doing it  it is the correct thing to do, what are the "rules" for class member. in other words why  not storing it as class member.

Comment: @user3717741 if you don't do this but store it as a data-member then you'll have trouble when calling the function from multiple threads